# Stuck on express routing

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

app.js file

```
// home route
app.get("/home", async(req, res)=>{
    let allCards = await  Card.find({});
    let skills = await Skill.find({});
    res.render("index", {allCards, skills});
})


// add new skill route
app.get("/home/newskill", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("newskill");
});

// submiting a new skill to the database
app.post("/home/newskill", async(req, res)=>{
    let {title, image}= req.body;
    let newskill = new Skill({
        image: image,
        title: title
    });
    await newskill.save();
    res.redirect("/home");
})


// signup route
app.get("/home/signup", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("signup.ejs");
});

// signup 2nd route
app.post("/home/signup", async(req, res)=>{
    let {userName, email, password}= req.body;
    let newUser = new User({
        userName: userName,
        email: email,
        password: password
    });
    await newUser.save().then(res =>{console.log(res)}).catch(err =>{console.log(err)});
    res.redirect("/home");
})


// login route
app.get("/home/login", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("login.ejs");
});

// login second route
// app.post("/home/login", async(req, res)=>{
//     let {userName, email, password} = req.body;
//     let user = await User.findOne({email: email, password: password})
//     res.render("index.ejs", {user});
    
// })
```

html login file

```
<div id="main">
    
    <form action="/home/login" method="post">
        <h3>Please input your login info</h3>
        <br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
        <br><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
        <br><br>
        <button class="btn btn-light">Submit</button>
    </form>


</div>
```

index.ejs file

```
<% for( let skill of skills) { %>
                <div>
                    <img src="<%= skill.image %>" alt="">
                    <p><%= skill.title %></p>
                </div>
            <% } %>
```

I'm a student and I'm currently working on a project that involves user login. I'm encountering an error when attempting to add a second route for user login in my application. The error message reads 'cannot get skill'. However, if I comment out the second login route, the error disappears. I'm looking for a basic explanation of why this error is occurring and some guidance on the fundamental principles of routing to help me avoid similar issues in the future. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Shahab ali and welcome to Stack Overflow. I know you understand when and how the error occurs in your mind, but readers need a bit more information, such as where the error is reported (front end/backend?), what the error message says and what the error call trace shows (which usually indicates which part of the software generated the error). Please update the post with this kind of information. Note that details of the error should be copy and pasted as text into the post when updating it: please do not create and post images of error details. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The second login route does not contain any errors, it is strange that the error disappears when you comment it out. This error message you mentioned, "cannot get skill", should be displayed when trying to access the "/skill" route, and it seems it does not exist in your server code. Check your code to see if you are trying to access this route at any point.

Comment: Just to reiterate:
This "cannot get" error normally appears when you try to access a route that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In the login post route (second login route), While rendering index.ejs that is looking for skills however you have not passed the skills while rendering it. After logging in you can redirect to /skills route you have used earlier or pass the skills while rendering index.

Answer (score 0):

In your first route you are using the `GET` method and sending the `login.ejs` page. The variable `skills` is not being utilised on `login.ejs` so there is no error:

```js
app.get("/home/login", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("login.ejs");
});
```

The second route is a `POST` request which is sending the `index.ejs` page with data contained in the `user` variable:

```js
app.post("/home/login", async(req, res)=>{
   let {userName, email, password} = req.body;
   let user = await User.findOne({email: email, password: password})
   res.render("index.ejs", {user});  
})
```

However, your `index.ejs` always expects a variable named `skills` to exist. When you post to `/home/login` there won't be a `skills` variable like there will be when you do a `GET` to `app.get("/home",...)`

My advice would be to use `if` in your `index.ejs` file like so:

```js
<%if (skills) { %>
   <% for( let skill of skills) { %>
      <div>
         <img src="<%= skill.image %>" alt="">
         <p><%= skill.title %></p>
      </div>
   <% } %>
<% } %>
```